# Advanced gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I know you can use a pattern like `*test*` to ignore any directory or file containing word `test`.

But now I'm looking for something more advanced.

```
|- Folder A
|  |- File A
|  |- File B
|- Folder B
|  |- File C
|  |- File D
|  |- Pro.txt
|- Folder C
|  |- Pro.txt
|- Folder D
   |- File E
   |- File F
```

I want to ignore all folders that directly contain the `Pro.txt` file like `Folder B` & `Folder C`.
I do not want to ignore just the file, I want to ignore the whole folder (with subfolders and files)

The file `Pro.txt` is empty and just an indicator that which folders I do not wish to be uploaded on git and is not required to exist.

And before you say it, I can not change the folder name to contain a specific word.

Comment: you can rename Pro.txt to .gitignore and put `*` in it

Comment: also : there isn't a way to tell "ignore directories which contain this specific file" in a gitignore file. See [`git help gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) for a description of the rules that can be described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon @IlyaBursov's comment, `git` doesn't just look for `.gitignore` in the root of your repository -- it looks for a `.gitignore` file in *every directory*.  So if you have:

```
.
├── Folder A
│   ├── File A
│   └── File B
├── Folder B
│   ├── File C
│   ├── File D
│   └── .gitignore
├── Folder C
│   └── .gitignore
└── Folder D
    ├── File E
    └── File F
```

And all those `.gitignore` files contain `*`, then running `git add .`
in the root of the repository results in:

```
$ git status
On branch main

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   Folder A/File A
        new file:   Folder A/File B
        new file:   Folder D/File E
        new file:   Folder D/File F
```

As you can see, `git` has ignored everything in `Folder B` (and in
`Folder C`, but since that directory was empty, the `.gitignore` file
is no-op; recall that `git` only tracks files, not directories).

Comment: a stupid gitignore thingy : a `.gitignore` file with `*` in it makes git ignore the .gitignore file itself ... If you want it to be versioned (so that it also applies to other people cloning your repo), you can add it on a one by one basis using `git add -f "Folder B/.gitignore"`, or add a second line `!.gitignore` to the .gitignore file.